# WCF service can't get data using Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm using Entity Data Model and WCF services to get and store information to MS SQL database. So far I've created 4 tables. While the the tables are not interconnected with relationships everything is fine, service works as expected, but once i update database tables and create FK's, after updating model service no longer works and throws error like this **Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.**

If I reference  Data model right in the client application and write exactly the same method as in  it works just fine.

Sample method from WCF service

```
public List<Inventory> getAll() {

        var list = Context.Inventories.OrderBy(c => c.DESCRIPTION).ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

Any advice or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are returned? Add following code into your hoster config

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name='traceListener' type='System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener' initializeData='C:\Trace.svclog'/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

After exception you can open this file and navigate to line that is highlighted with red color and get the detailed error message.

Also look at this [System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518978/system-servicemodel-communicationexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed)