# CommunicationException during WCF request, underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, exception, web-config

This question is a duplicate of [System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518978/system-servicemodel-communicationexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed) but it did not solve my problem.

I am using a WCF service that writes into and reads from a database. But in some cases the request cancells with a CommunicationException saying that the underlying connection was closed. No further details given.

I enabled tracing but the log shows no entries concerning this request. I tried setting the `MaxItemsInObjectGraph` to 65535 but nothing changed. Maybe my configs are misconfigured, can someone have a look at them?

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="Error.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Legen Sie die Werte unten vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Metadateninformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Damit in Fehlern Ausnahmedetails zum Debuggen angezeigt werden, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest. Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Ausnahmeinformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <!-- Umgeht eine CommunicationException, die auftritt, wenn der ObjectGraph überläuft -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65535"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDBUpdater" 
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 allowCookies="false" 
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 messageEncoding="Text" 
                 textEncoding="utf-8" 
                 transferMode="StreamedResponse" 
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <protocolMapping>
      <remove scheme="http" />
      <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDBUpdater" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Um das Stammverzeichnis der Webanwendung beim Debuggen auszuwählen, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest.
        Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Informationen über den Webanwendungsordner zu vermeiden.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDBUpdater" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        <binding allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://10.1.58.48/DBUpdate/UpdateService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDBUpdater"
        contract="UpdateService.IDBUpdater" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm not very familiar with WCF configuration. Is there anything wrong or why do I keep getting this error message?

Code example:

```
string cmd = @"SELECT trainer.TID, anrede.Anrede, trainer.Titel, trainer.Vorname, trainer.Nachname, trainer.Festnetz, trainer.Mobil, trainer.Email, trainer.Trainerstatus, trainer.Honorar
                           FROM trainer
                           left join anrede on trainer.Anrede = anrede.ID
                            Group by trainer.TID";
var client = new DBUpdaterClient();
dt = client.ExecuteReaderUGV(Helpers.GetUsername(), cmd);
```

Error appears after calling `ExecuteReaderUGV()`, the resulting data table object should have about 3500 entries. With smaller data tables (<50) it works fine.

Error message:
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

**UPDATE:**

We tracked the problem down to the key word `left join`. When replaced by `inner join` it works fine. However, it is not clear to us why this happens. When we access the database without the web service and execute the sql command with a `left join` it works. When we use the web service, it doesn't.

**UPDATE II:**

The problem is the condition at the `left join`: if the condition cannot be evaluated (for example one value does not exist) the web service call answers with a `Communication Exception`. Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: can you give a code sample of a complete call to the service that's giving you issue?

Comment: I have edited the question and added more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Successful solution:** Replace `DataTable` with `DataSet`

I dont know why but the exception is gone since then.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF return a Datatable, when you are creating the Datatable object you need to use this costructor:

```
var dt = new DataTable("Anything");
```

You can use this function:

```
   public DataTable ExecuteRequest(string requete)
    {

        var dt = new DataTable("Anything"); // this will resolve your problem
        if (requete!= string.Empty)
        {
            using (con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
               var cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, con);
               var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


                sda.Fill(dt);


            } 
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

i hope it will resolve your problem